# Is there a way to exclude text from being read within schema.org microdata?

Tags: handlebars.js, e-commerce, schema.org, microdata, google-shopping

I'm trying to prepare a Bigcommerce store I didn't create to be scraped by Google shopping after they recently made it free.

Our product descriptions have tabbed sections that show up in Google's important as a group of all of the tab names, then the main description body content, then the other tab content. This is because the description microdata itemprop is on the container for the whole tabbed section.

I updated the handlebars.js files so that itemprop is now just on the content of the description tab, which is better, but now it excludes the warranty and shipping information.

**Is there a way to flag certain text as not relevant/just navigation within an item with the microdata "description" itemprop so it doesn't show up in Google's automated pull?**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is such flag to omit sections within the 'description' itemprop.

You could look at marking up your warranty data with as an offer according to schema.org, your warranty may fit the criteria for an offer 'add on'
See docs here: https://schema.org/Offer

addOn being "an additional offer that can only be obtained in combination with the first base offer (e.g. supplements and extensions that are available for a surcharge)."

Also, for shipping -- you may be able to include the shippingDetails within offer, in addition to 'addOn'
shippingDetails being "Indicates information about the shipping policies and options associated with an Offer."